# Instance safe HashSet of BlockingQueue

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures, redis, blockingqueue

I need a data structure like `HashSet<Obj, BlockingQueue<Obj> > ds` which should be thread safe and instance safe. I can use **redisTemplate** to store this data structure as redis is thread safe but the problem is when i run multiple instances of my application, the `BlockingQueue` is not returning different object for concurrent thread in all instances all time. When i call  `take()` after getting the queue using key from redis, sometimes some instance getting same object. I need different object in all instances. I can use `Set` rather then `Queue` as `Set` will return object randomly. But still there is a chance to get same object in different instance. Any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: What does `front()` method do? Because i don't see that function inside java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue interface

Comment: @Szprota21, it will be take(). updated.

Comment: So are we are talking about a (potentially distributed) system, with multiple java applications needing to synchronize with some shared data storage? That is not a problem the application itself can solve. You need some other mechnism to ensure that the values an instance of your application takes out of the central storage are not given to anyone else. For example, you could delete the values in the central repo in an atomic transaction, mark them as taken somehow, or something similar.

Comment: What does "instance safe" mean?

Comment: I guess that "Instance safe" means that Op want's to run 5 instances (example) of his application, all of this instances will connect to redis and fetch some objects. And Op wants it to be synchronized between each instances. If I'm not wrong here this is impossible with something like "data structure".

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404921/how-could-a-distributed-queue-like-thing-be-implemented-on-top-of-a-rbdms-or-nos - it would seem that redis has everything you need for that based on the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441515/2513200)